# OpenERP - how to create a field hyperlink?

Tags: odoo

Attached is the picture of Bill of Materials partial view with hyperlink field. The field is "routing_id". I have searched code to find out how and where the hyperlink is done for this field, but without results.

How is the hyperlink created and how I can do it for another field? Thanks in advance for your help!

[image]

Comment: It's a related field. the link is generated automatically by the Odoo UI.

Comment: @DanielReis   It is many2one field in mrp_bom class. Here is the part of field definition: "'routing_id': fields.many2one('mrp.routing', 'Routing'....". Does this make any difference in your statement?

Comment: All many2one fields are presented like that. I don't see where the problem is,

Answer (score 0):

All many2one fields are presented like hyperlinks. Thanks to Daniel Reis for the answer.